# Weird ungrammatical PHP error msg when trying to set upload folder

Tags: php, upload

I've been getting this error, verbatim:

> // PHP setup Edit php.ini (try /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini search for "tmp" and make sure file uploads are, and that you have a tmp director of that name, with permissions set. To load the new php.ini, restart apache: apachectl restart

What's weird about this, besides the grammatical flaws, is that I get it no matter what I set upload_tmp_dir to in php.ini...or even if I remove php.ini entirely.

- I do an apachectl restart after each change. I've also tried rebooting.
- I believe I'm editing the right php.ini, because it's the one listed when I do a phpinfo(): /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini. It lists whatever upload directory I edit into it.
- This happens under Mac Lion with both Chrome and Firefox
- phpinfo tells me I'm running PHP Version 5.4.6
- I am the opposite of an expert.

Thanks for whatever help you can give me. I am preparing to D'oh slap myself.

Comment: What server software are you using? My Mac installation had PHP installed in two different places (one for command line, one for XAMPP), so I was editing the wrong php.ini.

Comment: that's not a php error message but from a script you are using.

Comment: Thanks, Dagon. Any ideas where that script would come from? Google doesn't know about it and it's not one that I've written.

Comment: Walid, I thought about that, but doesn't the fact that phpinfo points to the script I am in fact editing rule out that possibility? (See my last list item: I am not an expert.)

Comment: Wait... I have a thought. This isn't an error. This is a comment on the script surely. Have a look in the file. Is there a `<?php` at the start of the file. I think it's not running PHP it's merely outputting the PHP file as raw text.

Comment: Nice thought, Philip. But that's not the problem. Also, the error msg I'm seeing is definitely not in the php file.

Comment: when I do php -v, it tells me I'm using zend. (I didn't install it, but I didn't set up this machine.) Google tells me that Zend is a php ide. Does it install its own version of php, because that's the one my machine is running. It seems to be in /opt/local/bin. If I rename the php in that directory, php stops working on my machine. But I don't know how to tell apache to use the standard, pre-installed one. (Pardon the slew of bad assumptions in this.)

Comment: And.....here's the d'oh slap. Yup, Philip, you were right and I'm an idiot. I found the comment buried in a file I didn't realize was getting loaded. Hello hand, meet my forehead. Thanks for taking the time chasing down my wild goose.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a comment in a buried file.  Aaarrrggghh! Thanks to do those who offered suggestions. I am equally grateful and embarrassed.